# How to use the OR operator within a filter predicate when using _._2 in scala

Tags: scala, filter, functional-programming, pattern-matching, scala-collections

I have the code below that filters a tuple by checking if the 2nd element (an index number) matches with another variable.

```
statements.zipWithIndex.filterNot(_._2 == StatementsIntoTuples(statements).indexWhere(_.equalsIgnoreCase("PUSHPOP")) map {
 case (statement,_) => statement }
```

I am trying to use the OR operator to filter out by a second condition as shown below (1 is just an example)

```
statements.zipWithIndex.filterNot(_._2 == StatementsIntoTuples(statements).indexWhere(_.equalsIgnoreCase("PUSHPOP")) || _._2 == 1  )map {
     case (statement,_) => statement
   }
```

but it gives me an error of missing parameter type. I'm familiar when it comes to a single element as opposed to a tuple ie have used the code below in my code and works fine But think I'm probably doing something wrong and misunderstanding using `_._2`.

```
statements.filterNot(x => x.toString().contains("NOP") && x.isUnlabelled)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you used underscore twice. Consecutive underscores refer to consecutive lambda parameters, you only have one. You need to write it in a more explicit form:

```
statements.zipWithIndex
  .filterNot { case(_, index) => index == StatementsIntoTuples(statements).indexWhere(_.equalsIgnoreCase("PUSHPOP")) || index == 1  }
  .map { case(statement, _) => statement}
```